# Permission Denied while running the .ksh file

Tags: shell, unix

I have file with `.ksh` extension, and I have created a shell script to call this file in `java`.
When I call the shell script, it will read the file and run the procedure.

We have some different conditions defined inside the `.ksh` file, such as `BadFile` and `LogFile`.

If the `.ksh` file runs successfully, it will generate a log file in the server.

Whenever we call the shell script we get the error message "permission denied" when reading this `BadFile` and `LogFile`.

I tried to provide permission on the file system level, no luck.
I tried with `chmod 777 filename` etc.

Comment: Hi, I have provided you a solution below. Check with what account your java application run and check whether that account has access to the location of your shell script file or not and fix it.

Comment: Can you give more details? Show a simplified version of your script. Is a part of the script finished when you get the error or is the script itself forbidden? What happens when you call your script after performing `cd /` ? What statements are made with `BadFile`?

Comment: Here i am explain about the Manual step which following                                      
1. Going to server some path cd/path

Comment: Here i am explain about the Manual step which following                                      
1. Going to server some path cd/path
2. vi someFileName.csv (open in edit mode)
3. with some format entering test data ex :- Name "prem", desc "Test" etc
4. Save it the file
5. once more file is there in the same path with extension as .ksh
6. just running the file ./Filename.ksh
7. it will run the procedure and create test data 
8. Getting issue while running the .ksh file,,

Comment: about the bad File, in the .ksh file ,some condition are there, if we unable to process any records in .csv file, it will generate the .bad file in the directory

Answer (score 1):

It is very clear that your `Java` program does not have proper permission to execute the file. As you have mentioned that you have change the file permission to `777` you still need to check whether your `Java` application has permission to the path. Suppose your shell script file is in `/app/myapp/myshellscript.sh` now you need to check whether `Java` application has proper permission in directories `app` and `myapp` to access the script file. Only file execution permission to all does not going to solve your issue.

Check with what account/user/group your java application run and check whether that account has access to the location of your shell script file or not and fix it.

Comment: Thanks for your response, The permission issue get resolved with "Chown" with changing the user, Now new issue arise. Not getting issue as  "sqlplus: not found [No such file or directory]" could you please response to it.

Comment: Finally i am able to resolve this issue sqlplus - i specify
cd ~
. ~/.bash_profile
Now its working fine